# How to set timeout to RabbitMQ DefaultConsumer?

Tags: java, rabbitmq

I have an application which works as rabbitmq producer. I have applied RPC approach and there is no problem. Producer publishes message and consumes its response in replyQueues (temporary queue). Firstly, I have used QueueingConsumer for producer consuming and I used to set an timeout to nextDelivery(timeout) method. QueueingConsumer is deprecated now and In RabbitMQ offical site they have changed their RPC tutorial and They have used DefaultConsumer instead of QueueingConsumer. I have replaced QueueingConsumer with DefaultConsumer too. But there is a problem now:  How can I set an timeout to DefaultConsumer? Because if consumer does not sent any response, trash temporary queues remains in the broker. Old and new producer consuming part is below. Thanks for your helps.

Old producer consuming approach:

```
    consumer = new QueueingConsumer(channel);
    channel.basicConsume(replyQueueName, true, consumer);
    channel.basicPublish("", requestQueueName, props, message.getBytes("UTF-8"));

        while (true) {
            QueueingConsumer.Delivery deliver = consumer.nextDelivery(timeout);
            if (deliver.getProperties().getCorrelationId().equals(corrId)) {
                response = new String(deliver.getBody(), "UTF-8");
                break;
            }
        }

        return response;
```

new producer consuming approach:

```
      final BlockingQueue<String> response = new ArrayBlockingQueue<String>(1);

    Consumer consumer = new DefaultConsumer(channel) {
        @Override
        public void handleDelivery(String consumerTag, Envelope envelope, AMQP.BasicProperties properties, byte[] body) throws IOException {
            if (properties.getCorrelationId().equals(corrId)) {
                response.offer(new String(body, "UTF-8"));
            }
        }
    };

    channel.basicConsume(replyQueueName, true, consumer);

    return response.take();
```

Comment: Didn't know yet about Java's BlockingQueue interface. Awesome stuff...

Answer (score 2):

It solved. A timeout can be set to "response" object. Changes in the "new producer consuming approach" can be as following:

Timeout to response: `response.poll(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)` must be used instead of `response.take()`.